# Do a SELECT on all tables between 2 dates

Tags: php, mysql, loops, datediff

I have a Mysql Database with a table for each day, it goes this way: `my_table_20130310`, `my_table_20130311` ...

I want to do a select on all tables let's say between '2013/02/02' and '2013/03/28'

There is this stupide solution, which is to transform given dates into this:

```
'2013/02/02' => 20130202

'2013/03/28' => 20130328
```

cast then into (int) and then do a loop:

```
      $dbStartDate  = str_replace('/', '', substr($startDate, 0, 10));
      $dbEndDate    = str_replace('/', '', substr($endDate, 0, 10));

      for ($tbDate = $dbStartDate; $tbDate <= $dbEndDate ; $tbDate++) { 
        $res = 'SELECT * FROM my_table_' . $tbDate ;
        ...
        ... 
      }
```

But this is not a solution since it will try to parse all numbers between 20130202 and 20130328 (20130299, 20130245....)

An Idea ?

Thx guys

Comment: wait. Why do you want to have a table for each day? doesn't match sense. You can always use `GROUP BY` to group data by day.

Comment: I think the root of the problem is that you have a table for each day. If you can change the schema to make the day a column (indexed and possibly part of the key), your problems should disappear.

Comment: Why are you having separate tables for daily data, why not just add a column for date? Looks a bit... weird.

Comment: The data i'm dealing with is huge (I'm indexing...) so a table a day is better solution

Comment: Maybe try converting the start date to unix time, then add 86400 seconds and convert back to your YYYYMMDD format, add to array, and repeat until it is equal to end date, and then loop through the result array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$dbStartDate = new DateTime('2013/02/02');
$dbEndDate = new DateTime('2013/03/28');
$diff = $dbEndDate->diff($dbStartDate)->days; // get the difference in N days


// just a loop :p
$currentDate = $dbStartDate;
for($i=0;$i<=$diff;$i++){
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table_' . $currentDate->format('Ymd');
    date_add($currentDate, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 day'));
    // echo $query."<br/>"; // for testing purposes
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot, didn't know we could do it this way!

Answer (score 2):

In pseudocode:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime('2013-02-02');
DateTime endDate = new DateTime('2013-03-08');

for(DateTime d = startDate; d <= endDate; d = d.Add(new DateInterval('P1D')))
{
    res = 'SELECT * FROM my_table_' . d.format('YYYYmmdd');
    //...
}
```

Comment: You would change function call operateur from "." to "->" (but it's just a detail!) I think the format also would be (Ymd). thx a lot.

Comment: @vladimire Yeah, like I said it's pseudocode. Hopefully enough to give you the idea of the algorithm.